# Check if a node is parent of another node in React / React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Let's say I have a React node with id `14`. I want to check if this node is children of another node with id `2` in the tree. It doesn't necessarily needs to be a direct children, `14` can be nested in several other nodes, but it's, in the end, a children of `2` in the tree and `2` is its ancestor.

Is there any built-in function to do that?

**Edit**

I have several `ScrollView`s rendered in my app, and I want them to automatically handle the `TextInput`s they contain. I want to be able to check if an specific `TextView` is contained into one `ScrollView` or not.

Comment: Can you add some context? Why would you like to do that?

Comment: Done @DanielSchmidt

Comment: Wrote an answer, if you need some code examples, please let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use UIManager to verify if one node is a descendant of another one.

```
import { UIManager } from 'react-native'

UIManager.viewIsDescendantOf(targetNodeId, parentNodeId, (isDescendantOf) => {
  console.log(isDescendantOf)
})
```

Comment: Actually, I ended up making this function inside `UIManager` and submitted a PR to the react-native core :D

Comment: @amb Thanks for your work. Was looking for this, didn't find the answer on StackOverflow, so I had to dig in the React Native code base as it is not documented. This will help the next person who looks for it :).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the context of your question, I would recommend to add [context](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) to your component containing the scrollview and get the context in the component containing the input. There you may bind the passed callback to the input.

Comment: This is interesting, however I need to access the node's element to get its context. `findNodeHandle` returns an opaque node number that I'm struggling to find how with that number I can get the element.

Comment: Okay, I thing we both are referring to different context concepts. My conception of context is the React mechanism, which lets you specify prop-like content, which doesn't need to be propagated through the components hierarchy. My first question would be what you mean by "element context" and my second, why you don't use the ref property and bind it to the passed function, to get hold of the node "dom" element?

Comment: What I mean for the context is exactly what you have described. The thing is that I use `TextInput.State.currentlyFocusedField` to get the `tag` of the node. That `tag` is just a number, not a React component (I referred to that as an element, my fault), thus I can't access the context.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post but I'm currently trying to achieve something similar.

There is the function **getInstanceFromNode** that you can find in **ReactNativeComponentTree** (react-native/Libraries/Renderer/src/renderers/native/). It returns the component attached to the node ID.

And it has a "**_hostParent**" variable in which you get the whole component tree.